# The sea battle paradox and the soundness criterion

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

Again a short look at Aristotle's resolution (one of many) of the sea battle paradox:

> In one famous example about a hypothetical sea battle, [Aristotle] observes that the necessary truth of a mere proposition does not trump the uncertainty of future events.  Because it is necessarily true that there will be or will not be a sea battle tomorrow, we cannot conclude that either alternative is necessarily true. […] So the necessity that attaches to the proposition “there will or will not be a sea battle tomorrow” does not transfer over to the claim ‘that there will be a sea battle tomorrow” or to the claim “there will not be a sea battle tomorrow.”
>
> *– [IEP: “Aristotle: Logic”](http://www.iep.utm.edu/aris-log/#H4)*

The sea battle argument is based on the theorem (*P* ∨ ¬*P*) in propositional logic. In itself this theorem doesn't seem to give us anything absurd under the interpretation that *P* could stand for “there will be a sea battle tomorrow” – exactly for the reasons described above.

But the soundness criterion for propositional logic *is* about truth assignments: any truth assignment to propositional variables in a theorem will reduce to “true”. But doesn't this at least *hint* at the assumption that any propositional variable has **either** truth value “true” **or** “false” – which again gives rise to the sea battle paradox?

Comment: Not clear... A's argument is about the modal operator "necessary"; in a nutshell, the argument is aimed to show that "necessary" does not distribute  over "or", i.e. **□(p∨¬p)⊭□p∨□¬p**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA your comment is 100% pointless! Yeah, “necessity” can't be distributed over “or”, just like Aristotle said. If we stop here, everything's fine. Trivial! The real problem is that if every proposition has *always* a truth value and we believe that truths about the past are necessary, then the proposition becomes necessarily true or false – because it was already true or false in the past. Aristotle's way out of that is to claim that “the proposition was true/false before the event” cannot be maintained. But the soundness criterion hints at the opposite direction!

Comment: I am not sure what "soundness criterion" means, but if it means compositionality of truth values it is well-known that it does not hold for connectives in natural languages, and not only for [future contingents](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/future-contingents). Truth value of composites depending only on truth values of constituents is a crude idealization. Intuitionist logic is non-compositional, the law of excluded middle fails there. But one can combine it with semantic bivalence, as Aristotle does, as in [supervaluationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervaluationism).

Comment: So much of the argument depends on the term "soundness criterion" that a definition is essential before a meaningful answer is possible.

Comment: See [Future Contingents](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/future-contingents/) for a formalisation with tense logic: "It is essential to notice that the necessity at stake in the classical argument is a historical necessity. This means that what is not necessary at one moment may become necessary at another moment." This is not so for the "standard" approach to mathematical truth: it is not "tensed". **2+2=4** is true today as was yesterday and as will be tomorrow; this, it is necessarily true.

Comment: When you say: "propositional logic is about truth assignments", you must take into account these considerations.

Comment: For modern studies, see: Richard Gaskin, [The Sea Battle and the Master Argument](https://books.google.it/books?id=czuplVE-SEcC&printsec=frontcover), De Gruyter (1995), Jules Vuillemin, [Necessity or Contingency: The Master Argument](https://books.google.it/books?id=zh0RnQAACAAJ) (1996), Jaakko Hintikka, [The Once and Future Sea Fight: Aristotle's Discussion of Future Contingents](http://thatmarcusfamily.org/philosophy/Course_Websites/Readings/Hintikka%20-%20The%20Once%20and%20Future%20Sea%20Fight.pdf) (1964).

Comment: As well as: Jaakko Hintikka, [Time and Necessity: Studies in Aristotele's Theory of Modality](https://books.google.it/books?id=q58jelN1E88C), Clarendon (1973)